# vscode typescript intellisense is not inferring type from npm package

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to use a package called "@vite/connector". It is written in [typescript](https://github.com/vitelabs/vite-connect-client) and I am using it like this:

```
import Connector from '@vite/connector';

class Thing {}

const thing = new Thing();
const connection = new Connector({ bridge: 'wss://biforst.vite.net' });
```

When I hover my cursor over `thing`, it correctly shows that it is of type Thing like `const thing: Thing`, but when I hover over `connection`, it says `const connection: any`. Moreover, auto complete is not working for the various [methods](https://github.com/vitelabs/vite-connect-client/blob/master/src/core/index.ts). Why is this and how do I get the type to be inferred correctly and the autocomplete working?

If it helps, I had to use `declare module '@vite/connector';` in `typings/index.d.ts` to get the code to compile

Comment: " I had to use declare module '@vite/connector';" That's why

Comment: Shouldn't the types/methods be inferred anyways?